# How to compute the derivatives automatically within for-loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

For the purpose of generalization, I hope Matlab can automatically compute the 1st & 2nd derivatives of the associated function f(x). (in case I change f(x) = sin(6x) to f(x) = sin(8x))

I know there exists built-in commands called `diff()` and `syms`, but I cannot figure out how to deal with them with the index `i` in the for-loop. This is the key problem I am struggling with.

How do I make changes to the following set of codes? I am using MATLAB R2019b.

```
n = 10;
h = (2.0 * pi) / (n - 1);
for i = 1 : n
  x(i) = 0.0 + (i - 1) * h;
  f(i) = sin(6 * x(i));
  dfe(i) = 6 * cos(6 * x(i));   % first derivative
  ddfe(i) = -36 * sin(6 * x(i));   % second derivative 
end
```

Comment: I still don't know what `x` is. Can we say that `x=linspace(0,1,n)`? Or are there some other restrictions on it?

Comment: Notice `diff` calculates a finite difference - a numerical approximation for the derivative. `syms` uses the symbolic toolbox and, although it calculates the analytical expression for the derivative, it may run much slower than numerical calculations. You would also need the symbolic toolbox.

You coded the first and second derivatives by hand. Are you interested in approximating these derivatives for any arbitrary function or just want to type the function and its derivatives and calculate it for the set `x` (like using function handles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `subs` and `double` to do that. For your case:

```
% x is given here
n = 10;
h = (2.0 * pi) / (n - 1);
syms 'y';
g = sin(6 * y);
for i = 1 : n
  x(i) = 0.0 + (i - 1) * h;
  f(i) = double(subs(g,y,x(i)));
  dfe(i) = double(subs(diff(g),y,x(i)));   % first derivative
  ddfe(i) = double(subs(diff(g,2),y,x(i)));   % second derivative 
end
```

By @Daivd comment, you can vectorize the loop as well:

```
% x is given here
n = 10;
h = (2.0 * pi) / (n - 1);
syms 'y';
g = sin(6 * y);
x = 0.0 + ((1:n) - 1) * h;
f = double(subs(g,y,x));
dfe = double(subs(diff(g),y,x));   % first derivative
ddfe = double(subs(diff(g,2),y,x));   % second derivative
```

Comment: Thanks! helps a lot!

Comment: @q220085 my pleasure. you can accept it as your answer.

Comment: You don't need tick marks in `syms y`, and the `for` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: @David Do you mean by "`for` loop is unnecessary" it can be vectorized? Right?

Comment: Yeah take out the loop and all the `(i)` indexing, just make `x` in one statement.

Comment: @OmG One more question, Are ```syms 'y'``` and ```syms y``` different from each other?

Comment: @q220085 here, they are the same.